# InstanceNotFoundException when trying to get Hikari Pool active connections in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, hikaricp

I am trying to get the number of active connections in the Spring-boot Hikari pool. In my logs, it prints two pools naming `HikariPool-1` and `HikariPool-2`.

[image]

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HikariJmxElf {
    private final ObjectName poolAccessor;
    private final MBeanServer mBeanServer;

    public HikariJmxElf(final String poolName) {
        try {
            mBeanServer = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
            poolAccessor = new ObjectName("com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (" + poolName + ")");
        } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Pool " + poolName + " could not be found", e);
        }
    }

    public int getIdleConnections() {
        try {
            return (Integer) mBeanServer.getAttribute(poolAccessor, "IdleConnections");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public int getActiveConnections() {
        try {
            return (Integer) mBeanServer.getAttribute(poolAccessor, "ActiveConnections");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public int getTotalConnections() {
        try {
            return (Integer) mBeanServer.getAttribute(poolAccessor, "TotalConnections");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to get that data using an actuator info endpoint.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HikariPoolInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        builder
            .withDetail("connectionDetails", new HikariJmxElf("HikariPool-1").getActiveConnections())
            .build();
    }
}
```

The full error I'm getting is

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException:
> com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (HikariPool-1)

I have these questions.

1. mBeanServer server requires an Object name with the pool name. is HikariPool-1 isn't the actual name of if?
2. Is there a way to get all Hikari pools without going by their names?

Answer (score 0):

Once the access token has expired, we can refresh it by sending a POST request to the same URL as above, but containing the refresh token instead of username and password:

please check below link.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak

Comment: This isn't related to spring boot security because I'm using actuator Info. This line raises that exception. 
 -- return (Integer) mBeanServer.getAttribute(poolAccessor, "ActiveConnections");

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.